# Is file_get_contents() the only way for plugins reading local files OR does WP_Filesystem_Direct::get_contents() even work?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-filesystem

## Background

I'm developing a [plugin for WordPress](https://github.com/badAd/wordpress). I initially used `file_get_contents()` for two purposes:

1. A remote file (which I changed to `wp_remote_post()`)
2. A local file in the plugin dir (what this question is about)

WordPress staff told me to NOT use `file_get_contents()` for remote `_POST` requests (usage 1. above), but to use `wp_remost_post()` instead.

From their email concerning usage 1. (above):

> ### Using file_get_contents on remote files
>
> Many hosts block the use of file_get_contents on remote content. This is a security measure that we fully endorse.
>
> Thankfully, WordPress comes with an extensive HTTP API that can be used instead. It’s fast and more extensive than most home-grown alternatives. It’ll fall back to curl if it has to, but it’ll use a lot of WordPress’ native functionality first.

So, I did. But...

## Solving usage *1. A remote file* (above) got me to reading and thinking about a better tool for usage *2. A local file* (above)

In the [WordPress HTTP API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/http-api/) docs, there is no alternative for `file_get_contents()` on local files, nothing like `wp_file_get_contents()`.

*(I understand this may seem strange since local files of a plugin are often static, but I am writing extra files to save cost, and I politely don't want to open that discussion. Besides, [this approved plugin from someone else](https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/), [code here](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/string-locator/trunk/string-locator.php), uses `file_get_contents()`, thus proving my own need is legitimate, but it doesn't prove that `file_get_contents()` is 'proper' WordPress-practice.)*

From [this blog post](https://www.tutdepot.com/alternative-functions-file_get_contents/), clearly this was a big discussion for `file_get_contents()` for *remote files*. But, I don't see much on the web about a WordPress function for *local files*. From the post:

> Like many others I’ve used the native PHP function file_get_contents() to receive the content from a remote file because the functions is very easy to use. But is it the best way to do that? I see many scripts using that function and even WordPress plugins are using this function while WordPress has a native function to receive remote content.

...I want to take that discussion to *local files* and build this plugin right.

## My code (current and attempted)

I simply need to confirm whether a local file in the plugin directory exists, then confirm whether it contains a certain string. I thought it best to use `file_get_contents()` for local files in PHP from [this question on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059026/php-check-if-file-contains-a-string). But, this is WordPress. Currently, I am using:

```
if ( ( ! $wp_filesystem->exists ( $check_this_file ) )
 || (strpos ( file_get_contents ( $check_this_file ),
    $check_this_string ) === false ) )
```

I tried using [WP_Filesystem_Direct::get_contents](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_filesystem_direct/get_contents/) instead:

```
if ( ( ! $wp_filesystem->exists ( $check_this_file ) )
 || (strpos ( WP_Filesystem_Direct::get_contents ( $check_this_file ),
    $check_this_string ) === false ) )
```

...but I got this error:

> `Deprecated: Non-static method WP_Filesystem_Direct::get_contents() should not be called statically`

## What should I do?

I'm not sure because there isn't even a #get-contents tag on WP.SE at the time of asking, but the function exists both in the framework and in the docs.

I want to know the "WordPress way" for plugins to read a plugin file's contents for a string test:

- `file_get_contents()` (what I have now)
- `WP_Filesystem_Direct::get_contents()` (but how do I make it work without the error?)
- or some ***proper-reliable*** usage of `wp_filesystem()` or similar

Comment: Well, you should use `$wp_filesystem->get_contents()`, and that method simply calls the native PHP's `file_get_contents()`, so you may use it directly in your code - for reading local files/resources.

Answer (score 2):

The alternate of using `file_get_contents()` is to initiate `WP_Filesystem` and use its  `$wp_filesystem->get_contents` method.

Here is a clean example method on how to use it

**Example**

```
<?php
     /**
     * This method gets a list of the most popular Google web fonts. 
     * Initialize the WP filesystem and no more using file_put_contents function
     *
     * @see     wp_filesystem()
     * @see     get_parent_theme_file_path()
     * @return  array   A list of Google web fonts
     */
    function mm_get_google_fonts() {
 
    // Call globals
    global $wp_filesystem;

    // You have to require following file in the front-end only. In the back-end; its already included
    require_once ( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

    // Initiate
    WP_Filesystem();
     
    $local_file =   get_parent_theme_file_path( '/assets/json/google-web-fonts.json' );
    $content    =   '';
 
    if ( $wp_filesystem->exists( $local_file ) ) {

        // following is alternate to
        // $content = json_decode( file_get_contents( $local_file ) );

        $content = json_decode( $wp_filesystem->get_contents( $local_file ) );

    } // End If Statement
 
    return $content;
 
} 
?>
```

For more information you can [visit the official documenation of WP_Filesystem](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_filesystem/)

Answer (score 2):

$wp_filesystem->get_contents is wrong for this purpose, since you can't know what filesystem path the file is going to be accessible at using WP_Filesystem .  If the user has WP_Filesystem using chrooted FTP or SFTP to the WP install dir, the server path /path/to/site/wp will need to actually be /site/wp in order for WP_Filesystem to find the file. But if you're not chrooted, it's at /path/to/site/wp

To reliably read your file you need to instantiate WP_Filesystem_Direct and then use that.

```
$wpfsd = new WP_Filesystem_Direct( false );
$wpfsd->get_contents ( $check_this_file )
```

Comment: It seems you're saying that `WP_Filesystem` won't follow symlinks to the place where the web user has access. So `WP_Filesystem_Direct` is more reliable. This is very insightful!

Answer (score 0):

## `$wp_filesystem->get_contents()`

`$wp_filesystem->get_contents()` replaced `file_get_contents()` perfectly as a drop-in replacement. Of course, it must be initiated with `WP_Filesystem();` first.

Here is a before and after example...

Before:

```
if ( (strpos ( file_get_contents ( $check_this_file ),
    $check_this_string ) === false) ) {...}
```

After:

```
WP_Filesystem();
if ( (strpos ( $wp_filesystem->get_contents ( $check_this_file ),
    $check_this_string ) === false) ) {...}
```

Comment: 2023 update: another answer recommends `WP_Filesystem_Direct` instead of `WP_Filesystem` for more reliability.